# Problem with Subdivision Surface around curves

Tags: modifiers, subdivision-surface

I've looked high and low for fixes to my problem but have come to the conclusion that I am just not able to word my searches correctly, or that I have a very specific problem.

Anyway, what I am trying to do is create a human figure from a cube by extruding out and scaling down many faces to create a curve that fits my background image.

This is an image of my mesh in both front orthographic and a view from the side in perspective view without any subdivision surface modifiers.[image: Front Orthographic + side perspective]

Now when I apply the subdivision surface modifier, you can clearly see that the mesh is messed up around the armpit area. 
[image]

The same effect happened on a quick mesh I made for hands, feet and the groin area. This means that the problem is definitely due to how I am making the 'slits' for those areas.

I've no idea how to go about fixing the problem as everything I have tried has failed miserably.

Comment: You should probably start by watching some beginner tutorials on how to make a human figure

Comment: As Duarte suggested, you should follow some tutorials, your mesh has way too many horizontal edge loops and not enough vertical, so you won't have any good result with that, for example follow this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aAO4C_8y0w8